# Passing a $username to the @include file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass the `$username` after log in to the `@include(header.blade.php)` so that I can get the username at the top of all account pages. 
How can I do this?

----- `header.blade.php`

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="/profile/">Good day, {{ $username should go here }} </a></li>
         <li><a href="/logout/">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
```

----- `layout.master`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        @include('includes.head')
    </head>
        @include('includes.header')

        @yield('content')

        @yield('frontoffice')

        @include('includes.footer')
    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of ***Auth***

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{ Auth::user()->username}}
@else
    Guest
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to add the following into the `BaseController` class constructor;

```
View::share('user', Auth::user());
```

Now as long as you run the `BaseController`s construct via `parent::__construct()` within your own controllers constructors. The `$user` object will be available in all views generated by your controllers and all the views they contain.

The within your view access the username via `$user->username`.

#### Or

Use the `Auth` facade within the view. But I recommend the first.